# Wordpress won't serve js files through reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, azure, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've got a perfectly functioning wordpress site on Azure AND a main website as different Azure website. I want the main website to be a reverse proxy server so that all the wordpress content is served to the outside world from our main domain.

All the web server jiggering I've done appears to work properly: the browser finds/displays the content and the proxy web server has re-written all the URLs so that 'myblog.azurewebsites.net' is replaced by 'mydomain.com/blog' (I can see that it's all correct when viewing the html page source).

However, there are a few files that the browser can't access, most notably the js files in the wp-includes folder. A 403 Forbidden error is returned.

Why would the original site send the article content but not the js files? Is there something special about the wp-includes folder? Do I need to loosen some permissions on it?

I found this [somewhat related discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-behind-reverse-proxy-1?replies=4), but can't find a way to modify my wp-config.php file so everything works.